# Swing. Send an event from one JPanel to another JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have the class `TablesCountEditor` which extends `javax.swing.JPanel` on which there are 2 more panels.

```
public class TablesCountEditor extends javax.swing.JPanel {
   private final ComponentDictionaryNameCombobox componentDictionaryNameCombobox;
   private final CompositeConditionExpressionEditor conditionExpressionEditor;
   public TablesCountEditor() {
       componentDictionaryNameCombobox = new ComponentDictionaryNameCombobox(nodeContext, app, tablesCountData, dictType);
       conditionExpressionEditor = new CompositeConditionExpressionEditor(SbpUIComponentConfiguration.getRE(),
            nodeContext);
       dictionaryNameComboboxPanel.add(componentDictionaryNameCombobox);
       conditionPanelWithDictionary.add(conditionExpressionEditor);
   }
}
```

I want, that when there is an event of a choice of a comboboxon, which contains on `ComponentDictionaryNameCombobox` panel, I could catch it on the second form (`conditionExpressionEditor`), and execute the necessary actions with the selected element in the combo box on the first form.

And also vice versa, if there is an event on the second form, you need to somehow catch it on the first one.

Tell me, is there any mechanism in the swing for subscribing to events on the form or something like that? How can you solve this problem at all? Thank you.

Comment: `JComboBox` supports both the `ActionListener` and `ItemListener` observers, which provide notifications when the selected item changes, perhaps you should consider starting thre

Comment: *"Tell me, is there any mechanism in the swing for subscribing to events on the form or something like that?"* - Yes, they are called listeners, most components provide one or more. A "listener" is just an implementation of an observer pattern, which is basically what you're describing. If non of the available listeners support your operations, you can make your own

Comment: @MadProgrammer, please, give me example, using `listeners` in swing

Comment: [Writing Event Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I using `this.dictionarySourceEditor.addActionListener(new DictionaryComboBoxListener());`, It's work perfect, but how I can make something on another form, witch this event has come

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question leads to extending the way every component notify the subscribers about an event.

You should think about your first `JPanel` as a component. Like every component you can keep a list of `ActionListener`s in that for a specific component in the `JPanel`. For example if you have `JButton` in the first `JPanel` and in the second `JPanel` you want to be notified for the events on that JButton, you can have a `private List<ActionListener> buttonActionListeners;` an two methods for adding and removing action listeners to/from that list. Now only one another thing you should do to be complete is to add a direct `ActionListener` to that button and in the `actionPerformed` method call the `actionPerformed` method on all listeners in the `buttonActionListeners`:

```
public class FirstJPanel extends JPanel{
    private List<ActionListener> buttonActionListeners;
    //... 
    public FirstJPanel(){
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        buttonActionListeners = new ArrayList<>();
        //
        JButton myButton = new JButton("Click Me!");
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                for(ActionListener listener: buttonActionListeners){
                    listener.actionPerformed(e);
                }
            }
        });

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    public void addMyButtonActionListener(ActionListener a){
        if(!buttonActionListeners.contains(a))
            buttonActionListeners.add(a);
    }

    public void removeMyButtonActionListener(ActionListener a){
        buttonActionListeners.remove(a);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class SecondJPanel extend JPanel{

    public void SecondJPanel(){
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        FirstJPanel first = new FirstJPanel();
        first.addMyButtonActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "My button in the FirstJPanel Click!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this example a simple mechanism of listener subscribing is implemented in the `FirstJPanel` class. The `SecondJPanel` is a subscriber to the events of  `myButton` of the `FirstJPanel`. The implementation of `FirstJPanel` allows more than one subscribers to the events of `myButton` and many more components can be notified when `myButton` is clicked.

Hope this illustrate the idea well.

Comment: It's work perfect, but how can I transfer data from first panel to second panel? For example, I have the field `String test = "blah";` on the first panel and it is updated when you click. How can I pass the value of this field to the second panel?

Comment: @All_Safe: In a more global point of view, the strategy of passing data from one class to another class is very depend on the whole design of an application and there's not a single solution for that. One way is to have a `getTest()` for that `test` field in the first panel, and when your subscribed actionListener in your second panel got called you can infer that `test` value is changed and you can call that `getTest()` method to get the value.

Comment: @All_Safe: Another way is to simulate mechanism of `ValueChangeEvent` propagation for changes of that `test` field's value. Very similar to `ActionListener` list, you can have a list of `ValueChangeListener` in your class for that field/fields. Then similarly you should have add/remove methods for that list. Finally in the actionListener in which you are changing that field's value, you can create a `ValueChangeEvent` object and pass it to the `valueChanged` method of those listeners. Again in your second panel you can subscribe a ValueChangeListener to first panel and it will work the same.

Comment: @All_Safe: Another way is to use `PropertyChangeSupport` in your first panel and let the second panel subscribe a `PropertyChangeListener` to panel one. You can find out about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html

Comment: @All_Safe: Finally if you've found this answer useful and suitable for your question, you can mark it as the answer to your question by selecting the checkbox on the left of this answer.